# why is sleep() making my entire code wait

Tags: python, pygame

why is this not working? the sleep function is making everything wait but I don't want it too, I only want the things under sleep() to wait. also, the while loop is making the entire thing crash. I've asked this multiple times and have gotten nothing that works. this project is due tomorrow and I've tried everything.

```
pygame.init()
from time import sleep

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400))

PINK = (255,192,203)
WHITE = (255,255,255)


screen.fill(PINK)
pygame.display.update()


font = pygame.font.SysFont("mvboli", 72)


text = font.render("loading", True, WHITE)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.center = (225,40)
screen.blit(text,textrect)


#make the animation

while True:

    sleep(1)
    text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.center = (350,40)
    screen.blit(text,textrect)
    sleep(0.5)
    text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.center = (370,40)
    screen.blit(text,textrect)
    sleep(0.5)
    text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.center = (390,40)
    screen.blit(text,textrect)
    sleep(0.5)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, PINK, (340,0,100,500))

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: From the doc: "time.sleep(secs) Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds.". This is exactly the expected behavior.

Comment: You never call update since it is not in the loop

Comment: Congrats, you just discovered the first rule of GUI development - never block the main loop thread.

Whatever requires `sleep()` should be executed on another thread.

Comment: Have you tried putting  `pygame.display.update()` in your while loop?

Comment: You got a pretty detailed answer over on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747478/3285730). Have you read through that?

Answer (score 0):

yes I've got it to work now because I put `pygame.display.update()` after everytime I made another dot after loading